# How do I get the raw href attribute from a WatiN Link object?

Tags: .net, html, unit-testing, watin

Let's say I have a hyperlink representation in HTML, like so:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

If I obtain a WatiN.Core.Link representation of said link, I should like to inspect its *href* attribute. However, if I call GetAttributeValue("href") on the Link object, it doesn't return the raw href value ("/"), instead it translates it to the absolute URL: *http://myserver/*.

How do I get the raw href value, i.e. "/" in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WatiN doesn't seem to have any direct way of circumventing the translation of the href attribute :( At least going by what I've been told on the watin-users mailing list.

Comment: The main challenge is that IE returns the full URL from the href attribute. This is not a problem with WatiN, it's a problem with IE.

Comment: Aha, interesting snafu. Good old IE.